# Set OCR register in interrupt?

Tags: c, arduino, avr

On ATmega 32u4 I've got two timers. One is for measuring ticks between interrupts and second which counts 1/60 of number of ticks. I'm not sure I'm allowed what I'm doing and if that is correct. If you could tell me what is wrong I would greatfull.

```
void setup(){
    EIMSK |= (1 << INT2); //INT2 enable
    EICRA |= (1 << ISC21) | (1 << ISC20); //INT2 RISING EDGE
    DDRD &= ~(1 << PD2); //PD0 (INT0)(3) as input
    PORTD &= ~(1 << PD2); //PD0 pulldown

    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS11); //prescaler 8
    //TIMER3 - 1/60
    TCCR3A |= (1 << WGM32); //CTC Mode
    TCCR3B |= (1 << CS31); //prescaler 8
    TIMSK3 |= (1 << OCIE3A); //compate interrupt enable
    sei();
}

ISR(INT2_vect) {
    TCNT3 = 0;
    OCR3A = TCNT1 / 60;
    TCNT1 = 0;
    degree = 30;
}

ISR(TIMER3_COMPA_vect) {
    Color * currentColor = &bColor;
    if (degree == 0)
        degree = 59;
    else degree--;
    if (degree == time.second)
        currentColor = &sColor;
    else if (degree == time.minute)
        currentColor = &mColor;
    else if (degree % 5 == 0 && degree / 5 == time.hour)
        currentColor = &hColor;

    //set pwm
    RedReg = currentColor->Red;
    GreenReg = currentColor->Green;
    BlueReg = currentColor->Blue;
}
```

Comment: Do you want a code review or is something actually not working as expected? And from the code you posted its not really clear what you intend to achieve. In general there is nothing wrong with setting OCR in the interrupt handler.

Comment: Yeah, it works not like I intended to. INT2 interrupt has signal at 120Hz frequency. The PWM I mentioned in code controls LEDs. So after this code i should be able to see very short blinks of LEDs. But there is no blinks. I wondered what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I've edited code above. It should tell more about what timer3 interrupt does. Color and time are structs with volatile variables. I have to mention that if there is no INT2 signal LEDs blinks randomly.